# How do I change the Embedded Video using separate links on the same page?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a video embedded using iframe. Just the standard code you get from YouTube.

I've been searching online to find a solution. That solution is that I would have a table underneath the embedded video and each table entry is a link. When the user clicks on the link the embedded video changes to that video.

All I have found so far is video players that require the .mp4, .ogg, .webm  videos to be stored on the hosting server.

Any code or even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my quick demo for your requirements http://jsbin.com/oyuxon/1/edit

In general, I don't know how your player handle the video URI, so this is just the suggestion:

- Save the video URI in a `data` attribute of each `li` item. I don't know why you need a `table` but I think a list is more suitable semantically. You can modify to use a table as well.
- You JavaScript (I used jQuery) to handle the `click` event in each `li` element, replace the video URI of your player by the value of the `data` attribute of this `li`.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: Hey, this is a great help! However I'm having problems getting the playlist to work. I.e. When I click on the video in the list nothing happens. 

The Javascript you wrote, is that separate to Jquery or actually part of it. I think that may be where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The script I wrote is separated from jQuery. You need to include the jQuery libray in your head before my script. Besides, can you tell me how to make your player play a specified video? This maybe help a lot.

Comment: Ah, I see :D This is the page I'm working on

http://melrosefilm.com/othercredits

The videos are link through the table at the moment.

The Production titles highlight on hover and when clicked take you to the video. As you know, with the help of your code I can now link them up so that the video above simply changes. Just got to figure out how to adjust it to the table :D

Comment: That's another thing, will I be able to adjust this so it plays vimeo as well?

Comment: Of course, you just need edit the `playerObj.attr('src', ... )` to replace the youtube video url by the vimeo video url: `"http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + videoId` You also remember to set the `id` of the `iframe` correctly as well as using the right video id to the `data-video` attribute of each `li` element :)

Comment: I saw your updated problem. You need to remove the `id` from `tr`, add a `class` to the correct `td` element (which you want user to click), update the javascript and css. This is my updated demo http://jsbin.com/oyuxon/2/edit

Comment: I got it to work with YouTube, however if I change playerObj.attr('src', ...) to replace the YouTube video URL with Vimeo then I won't be able to use YouTube video. I have a mixture of both YouTube and Vimeo. Is there anyway to add to the script to recognise both or have a separate script for each and id the <td>'s?

I really appreciate all of your help btw :)

Comment: Yes, feel free to use another attribute of `td` such as `data-videotype` (you can name it `data-` what you want) and use it value to distinguish whether use Youtube url format or Viemo url format.

Comment: You are awesome! Got it working just how I want it. Thank you so much for your help!